# Geometry find length given altitude - Is my understanding correct?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Question: For the the triangle $ABC$ , $BC=10$ and $AB=AC=13$. Given that $AD$ is a median and $BE$ is an altitude, find what $DE$ is equal to.

Well I construct the triable and I know that AD breaks BC into two equal parts of $5$. And that both $BE$ and $AD$ form right triangles.

If I look at triangle $BCE$, with angle $E$ being $90$ degrees, how can I say that $DE=DC=5=BD$

That's the answer, but I'm unsure as to why. I was leaning to thales theorem, where I can see $BDC$ as a diameter of a circle, that has angle $E$ being $90$ degrees. So they're all radius on the circle? Thus equal to 5?

Comment: You are correct, any particular reason for you to question your solution?

Comment: I was wondering if my rationale behind using thales is correct? I'm not sure exactly why, as I drew the picture to scale and DE just looks equal to BD and DC. Does Thales here only hold if angle E is equal to 90?

Comment: If E was not 90 degrees, then the line BC would not be the diameter of $\triangle{BCE}$'s circumcircle.

Comment: You can see proofs for what you used (the center of the circumcircle of a right triangle lies on its hypotenuse.) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem#Converse)

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! I understand now!